# Odd behaviour in C

Tags: c

So, I put together these two algorithms:

```
int digitCount(int num){
    int count;
    while (num) {
        num /= 10;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

int digitSplit(int num, int digit) {
    int i, base = 1, count = digitCount(num);
    for(i = 1; i <= count + 1 - digit; i++)
        base *= 10;
    return num % base / (base / 10);
}
```

While I understand that they may not be optimal, the digitSplit gives me some very odd behaviour:

```
for (i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%d", digitSplit(432, i));
```

This one always crashes regardless of the setup.

```
printf("%d, %d, %d", digitSplit(432, 1), digitSplit(432, 2), digitSplit(432, 3));
```

This one puts out 0, 0, 2.

```
printf("%d", digitSplit(432, 1));
printf("%d", digitSplit(432, 2));
printf("%d", digitSplit(432, 3));
```

These put out 4 3 2 run separately, otherwise they crash the program => `for`-loop.

No idea why this is happening obviously, my `digitSplit` is the reason but how does the 0, 0, 2 come about?

Comment: `digitCount` should initialize `count` to zero.

Comment: `num%base/(base/10)` is the same as `num%base/(1/10)` same as `num%base/(0)` kaboom division by 0!

Comment: I suggest you crank up your compiler warnings.

Comment: Also use a debugger and step through your program. Look at the values of everything

Comment: for readability, and good programming practice, and ability to document variables and code,  Place only one variable declaration per line and place each code statement on a separate line.

Comment: @ouah actually the only way that is true is when you choose a digit out of range which i didn't do and while granted, my algorithm is not prepared for that, it doesn't have anything to do with my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few problems that may arise in C:
If you don't initialize a variable, it has the value of what last altered that bit of memory. It is always good form to initialize your variables with a value but in C it is extra important:

```
int digitCount(int num){
    int count = 0;
    while (num) {
        num /= 10;
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

What you are returning in digitSplit() is not correct. You want to shift a particular digit so that it is in the one's place, and then isolate the digit with mod 10. First we have to shift the digit we want to the one's place, by dividing num by 10^(count-digit), not 10^(count+1-digit). Let 10^(count-digit) = base, so we have
(num/base). Now we need to only get the one's place. We do this with mod:

```
int digitSplit(int num, int digit) {
    int i, base = 1, count = digitCount(num);
    for(i = 1; i <= count - digit; i++)
        base *= 10;
    return (num/base)%10;
}
```

Comment: " it has the value of what last altered that bit of memory" - that's something that can appear to happen, but not part of the language specification.  Formally it has an *indeterminate value* and they can behave differently. For example `count - count` might not give `0`, or the compiler could even optimize the whole thing out.

Comment: thank you  for the detailed answer, that was it. my function is returning the correct values but i can see how your calculation is better!